# Scraping form elements in selenium python without specifying class/ID?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

For other pages I specified the elements, but this pages field is dynamic based on the zip. Is there a way to scrape the values, in the form since they will change? I don't want to have to specify for each zip code it would be very time consuming. Is there a way to just scrape the values in the form without specifying the class/Id? I don't want to scrape the whole page just the values in the form.

```html
<h3>View/Change Coverage Summary</h3>
</div>

<div class="row visable-sm hidden-md hidden-lg text-center">
  <a href="#understandingVideoModal" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#understandingVideoModal">


    <div class="help-center-video-text">
      <div>
        <div><img src="/TGRV2/images/refresh/icon-play.svg" alt="Play icon"></div>
      </div>
      Not sure what kind of coverage you need? This 3&#8209;minute video explains the most common coverage options.
    </div>




  </a>
  <button type="button" class="close close-btn-mobile" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block;" class="close-btn-mobile" >&times;</span>
                                        </button>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
  <label for="priorInsList" class="col-md-6 control-label">
                                                Policy Type
                                                    
                                                        <a href="javascript:popup_help_cms('../help/qfptype/MO');" class="helpText">
                                                            <img src="/TGRV2/images/help-icon.svg" class="helpTextIcon">
                                                        </a>
                                                    
                                            </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <select name="policyType" onchange="showRecalculate(); showRecalculateAboveFold()" class="form-control">
      <option value="N" selected="selected">Base</option>
      <option value="Y">Restricted</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-6 control-label">
                                                    Liability Bodily Injury / Property <span class="text-img-no-wrap">Damage <a href="javascript:popup_help_cms('../help/qflibipd/MO');" class="helpText"><img src="/TGRV2/images/help-icon.svg" class="helpTextIcon"></a> <a href="#liabilityVideoModal" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#liabilityVideoModal"><img src="/TGRV2/images/btn-video-icon.svg" class="helpTextIcon play-video-icon"></a></span>
                                                </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select name="bipdLimits" onchange="propagateChange(new Array('umbiLimit','uimbiLimit','umbiAndUmpdLimit', 'umpdDed', 'umbiLimitStack', 'uimbiLimitStack', 'supplementaryUmbiLimit', 'umConversion', 'uimbiAndUimpdLimit'), getLimit('bipdLimit', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value));propagateChange(new Array('umpdLimit'), getLimit('bipdLimit', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value), 2);
                                                        showRecalculate(); showRecalculateAboveFold(); checkStateMin(this,'0','null/25');
                                                        if (this.form.elements['supplementaryUmbiLimit']) {
                                                        updateUmbi(this.form.elements['supplementaryUmbiLimit'].options[this.form.elements['supplementaryUmbiLimit'].selectedIndex].value)
                                                        }
                                                        if (this.form.elements['umConversion']) {
                                                        updateUmbiCT();
                                                        }
                                                        if (this.form.elements['uimpdLimit']) {
                                                        updateUimpdLimits()
                                                        }
                                                        if (false) {
                                                            UpdateUimpdBasedOnUMPD()
                                                        }
                                                        if (false) {
                                                            updateUmbiUimbiUmpdNC(this)
                                                        }
                                                        if (false) {
                                                            updateUmbiUimbiSD()
                                                        }
                                                        if (false) {
                                                            updateEuimStack();
                                                        }
                                                        if (false) {
                                                            updateUmbiNH()
                                                        }" id="umBiPdLimitsSelect" class="form-control">
      <option value="25/50/25" selected="selected">$25,000/$50,000/$25,000</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<!--modals-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal-group-selection">
  <div id="liabilityVideoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
      <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe id="liabilityVideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/237773185?api=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
                                                                        </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="uninsuredVideoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
      <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe id="uninsuredVideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/237772805?api=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
                                                                        </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="compVideoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
      <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe id="compVideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/237773309?api=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
                                                                        </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="understandingVideoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
      <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe id="understandingVideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/237772964?api=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
                                                                        </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end of Modals-->







<script language="javascript">
  var umbiLimits = new Array();
  limitIndex = 0;

  umbiLimits[limitIndex++] = new coverageMapEntry('$25,000/$50,000',
    new coverageLimit('$25,000/$50,000',
      '25/50',
      '25/50'));

  //Add less than or equal rule to UMBI
  for (var i = 0; i < umbiLimits.length; i++) {

    umbiLimits[i].limit.addRule('firstOptionAlwaysAvailable', 'OR', '');

    umbiLimits[i].limit.addRule('secondOptionAvailableIfNoCoverageForFirst', 'OR', 'coverageLimits[selectBoxId][0].limit.value');

    umbiLimits[i].limit.addRule('availableIfLimit_LE_LinkedLimit', 'OR', '');

  }
  coverageLimits['umbiLimit'] = umbiLimits;
</script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-6 control-label">
                                                Uninsured Motorist Bodily <span class="text-img-no-wrap">Injury <a href="javascript:popup_help_cms('../help/qfumbi/MO');" class="helpText"><img src="/TGRV2/images/help-icon.svg" class="helpTextIcon"></a></span>
                                            </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select name="umbiLimit" onchange="updateUmStack();
                                                if (true) {
                                                    propagateChange(new Array('umpdLimit', 'umpdDed'),
                                                        getLimit('bipdLimit', this.form.elements['bipdLimits'].options[this.form.elements['bipdLimits'].selectedIndex].value),2);
                                                    if (true) {
                                                        propagateChange(new Array('uimbiLimit'),
                                                            getLimit('bipdLimit', this.form.elements['bipdLimits'].options[this.form.elements['bipdLimits'].selectedIndex].value));
                                                    }
                                                    if (false) {
                                                            updateEuimStack();
                                                    }

                                                }
                                                showRecalculate(); showRecalculateAboveFold();" id="umbiLimit" class="form-control"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "driver[0].firstName").send_keys("Sarah")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "driver[0].middleInitial").send_keys("J")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "driver[0].lastName").send_keys("Jones")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "driver[0].dob").send_keys("04221998")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "register-switch").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label")[0].click()
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "driver[0].maritalStatus").send_keys("Single")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "primary_phone_number").send_keys("6155551212")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "sr22Radio1").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label")[1].click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "daccCntDiv0").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label")[1].click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "excludedDriversFlag").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label")[1].click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-success")))
```

Comment: I got it to print to the .csv by indenting the lines, but it's only printing the headers not the values for each drop-down.
 option_value = option_element.get_attribute("value")
            option_text = option_element.text
            print("Option Value:", option_value)
            print("Option Text:", option_text)
with open("form_data.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:  
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)   
    csv_writer.writerow(["Form Element Name", "Option Value", "Option Text"])